# How to check if a file exists in the system.DocumentsDirectory in lua (Corona SDK)?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Can i check if a file exists in system.DocumentsDirectory in Corona sdk?

How can i do that?

```
if ( myGameSettings exists ) then 

else

end
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

To check if a file exists you would do something like this:

```
--> Specify the path
local path = system.pathForFile( "myGameSettings.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

--> This opens the specified file and returns nil if it couldn't be found
local fh = io.open( path, "r" )


if fh then

   --> File Found

else

   --> File not found

end
```